# Read csv and create csvs/append rows in a single loop

Tags: python

Wrote a script that reads a single csv file and creates new csvs based on the values within the first 2 fields.  Then iterates through a 2nd time to append the rows to the proper csv.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this as well as lower the execution time?  Can I do this in a single read iteration?

```
import csv

base_filename = '_Template_.csv'
in_path = 'C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Test\\'
out_path = 'C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Test\\Completed\\'
in_filename = 'Source.csv'
in_file = open(in_path + in_filename, 'rb')
rdr = csv.reader(in_file)
rdr.next() #skip header row

for row in rdr: #create files and write header rows
    with open(out_path + row[1] + '_Template' + row[0] + '.csv', 'wb') as out_file: #uses values from fields 1 and 2 to create new filename
        wtr = csv.writer(out_file)
        wtr.writerow([str(x) for x in range(1,10)])

in_file.seek(1)

for row in rdr: #appened row to correct csv
    out_filename = row[1] + '_Template_' + row[0] + '.csv'
    split_filename = out_filename.split('_')
    if row[1] == split_filename[0] and row[0] == split_filename[2][:-4]: #check if value 1 & 2 equal values split from filename
        with open(out_path + out_filename, 'ab') as out_file:
            wtr = csv.writer(out_file)
            wtr.writerow((row[1:10]))
```

**Edit**

here's a sample of the source data and desired output.

```
Source.csv  
product,id,email,firstname,lastname,date,revenue,average,count1,count2
car,1,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/1/2015,600,50,1,2
car,1,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/2/2015,500,50,1,2
boat,1,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/3/2015,400,50,1,2
car,2,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/4/2015,300,50,1,2
boat,3,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/5/2015,200,50,1,2

1_Template_car.csv 
id,email,firstname,lastname,date,revenue,average,count1,count2 
1,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/1/2015,600,50,1,2
1,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/2/2015,500,50,1,2

1_Template_boat.csv
id,email,firstname,lastname,date,revenue,average,count1,count2
1,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/3/2015,400,50,1,2

2_Template_car.csv 
id,email,firstname,lastname,date,revenue,average,count1,count2 
2,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/4/2015,300,50,1,2

3_Template_boat.csv  
id,email,firstname,lastname,date,revenue,average,count1,count2
3,first.last@something.com,first,last,1/5/2015,200,50,1,2
```

Comment: Example csv and output would help.

Comment: The current state of the code makes it unnecessarily difficult to review. Can you use more intermediate variables and add some comments? For instance, `base_filename[-4:]` appears to always be the extension `'.csv'`, so call it that.

Comment: Made the appropriate edits.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You could try with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). I'd read the CSV into a `DataFrame` (see [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)). then you can simply `group_by` using the first 2 columns and finally write the resulting groups. It should be a few lines of code and very efficient.